# $E(S_T^2)\not=E (\sum_{i=1}^T \sigma_i^2) $ when $E|T|<\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk, stopping-times

I am currently learning random walk and come across a problem concerning stopping time.

The question asks to give an example that $X_1,X_2,...$ independent r.v. with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$, and
$$E(S_T^2)\not=E (\sum_{i=1}^T \sigma_i^2) $$  when $E|T|<\infty$ and $T$ is a stopping time.

I am not sure how to construct such example as so far what I learned are all iid case and in iid case the above would be an equality. I know that in iid case and $E|T|=\infty$ there could be such inequality by letting $T=\min \{n: S_n=1\}$ of a symmetric simple random walk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $$\mathbb{P}(X_n = 2^n) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = -2^n)=\frac{1}{2}$$ and set $$T := \inf\{n \geq 1; X_n = 2^n\}.$$ $T$ is a stopping time (with respect to the canonical filtration) and $$\mathbb{P}(T=n) = \frac{1}{2^n}. \tag{1} $$ This shows in particular that $$\mathbb{E}T = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \mathbb{P}(T=n)<\infty.$$ Moreover, since

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} 2^n = 2^{N}-2, \tag{2}$$

we have

$$S_T = \sum_{n=1}^{T-1} X_n + X_T = \sum_{n=1}^{T-1} (-2^n) + 2^T = 2.$$

Hence, $\mathbb{E}(S_T^2)=4$. On the other hand,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{n=1}^T \sigma_i^2 \right) &= \mathbb{E}\left( \sum_{N=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N 2^i 1_{\{T=N\}} \right) \\ &\stackrel{(2)}{=} \mathbb{E} \left( \sum_{N=1}^{\infty} (2^{N+1}-2) 1_{\{T=N\}} \right) \\ &\stackrel{(1)}{=}  \sum_{N=1}^{\infty} (2^{N+1}-2) \frac{1}{2^N} = \infty. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Ha, thank you, @saz! I have read your answer and I think it is right. Any motivation that how you came up with this solution? Or something you would like to explain that why it works?

Comment: @BrianDing Somehow it's because the expectation $\mathbb{E}X_n$ is growing very fast. In the iid case, $\mathbb{E}X_1<\infty$ implies in particular that the probability for large jumps is small. In this example this is totally different: With one step we can "undo" all the previous steps.

Comment: @saz - $\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}2^n = 2^N - 2$, not $2^N-1$ (the sum here is starting at $n=1$).

Comment: @Math1000 Ah, right, thanks.